# Refresh canvas everytime I want to download a new image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

i'm working on a web app where you can upload an image, put a png image over, and download the image with the sticker applied.

For that i'm using html2canvas, and it's working fine, you upload your photo, choose the png and download the new image, so far everyting is fine, but if you want to change the png and download the new image it will dowload the first image again with the first png. Im checking and im creating everytime a new canvas, but evertyme the download button uses the first canvas. How could i refresh that canvas to donwload the last one everytime?

This is the code:

```
<script>
   const capture = () => {
     const body = document.querySelector('#ImagenLista');
     body && (body.id = 'CapturaPantalla');
     html2canvas(document.querySelector("#CapturaPantalla")).then(canvas => {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     }).then(() => {
       var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
       canvas.style.display = 'none';
       var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream");
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       a.setAttribute('download', 'YoSoyYVoyA.jpg');
       a.setAttribute('href', image);
       a.click();
     });
   };
   
   const btn = document.getElementById('DescargaImagen');
   
   function FuncionDescarga() {
   btn.addEventListener('click', capture);
   
   }
   
</script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where are you creating your new canvas?

Comment: Well, everytime I use the download button a new canvas is created inside the HTML because of this line: 

body && (body.id = 'CapturaPantalla');

It appears at the bottom of the webpage with a new <canvas>